# Springboot Devtools not hot reloading?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, hot-reload

I haven't used spring in a while, and I'm trying to get spring boot dev tools to perform hot reloading. I've imported the web and spring boot dependencies from start.spring.io project generator and made a uri for "/hello". I can run the project but changing the uri values doesn't hot reload and I don't believe that the hot reloading is working. From what I've found on searching the internet, the only necessary step is to add the hot reloading dependency in your pom file:

```
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                        <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
```

My entire pom.xml file is as follows (generated from the start.spring.io website):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>java_app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>java_app</name>
        <description>Web Project</description>

        <properties>
                <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                        <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build> 
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>

</project>
```

And my web uri file is as follows (works, but without hot reloading):

```
package com.java.java_app;
  
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class JavaAppApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(JavaAppApplication.class, args);
        }

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name){
                return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
        }

}
```

This is as simple an application as I think it is possible to build, so I'm confused on what extra necessary step is needed to make hot reloading work. It does not appear to be documented say here (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-devtools) other than to add the dependency. If it matters I'm running ubuntu 20.04.

EDIT:

I am running the application in the terminal on port :8080 and using vim to modify the uri file while the application is running. Since java has a lot of plugins for various IDEs someone suggested that it is worth mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using an IDE you can use `./mvnw compile` and the project will recompile while the editor is running.

Comment: In short, you mean  while your Spring application is running (`./mvnw spring-boot:run
`) , you have to recompile in another terminal `./mvnw compile`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to have hot reload if you aren't using an IDE

for vim users

```
// Add below into your ~/.vim/ftplugin/java.vim
function! SearchFileBackwards(fn)
    let fp = expand('%:p')
    let pos = len(fp) - 1
    while pos > 0
        let pom = ""
        if fp[pos] == '/'
            let pom = strpart(fp, 0, pos + 1) . a:fn
            if filereadable(pom)
                break
            endif
        endif
        let pos = pos - 1
    endwhile
    return pom
endfunction

function! BuildMavenProject()
    let pom = SearchFileBackwards("pom.xml")
    if pom != ""
        exec '!mvn -f '.SearchFileBackwards("pom.xml").' compile'
    else
        echohl WarningMsg | echo "No pom.xml found." | echohl None
    endif
endfunction

" comment out below line to enable automatic build on maven project.
" autocmd BufWritePost *.java :call BuildMavenProject()

" Press <F8> to build current maven project.
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <F8> :call BuildMavenProject()<CR>
```

and if you are using nvim here is the code

```
// this file should be created in ~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/java.lua
function SearchFileBackwards(fn)
  local fp = vim.fn.expand('%:p')
  local pos = #fp
  local pom = ""
  while pos > 0 do
    if fp:sub(pos, pos) == '/' then
      pom = fp:sub(1, pos) .. fn
      if vim.fn.filereadable(pom) == 1 then
        break
      end
    end
    pos = pos - 1
  end
  return pom
end

function BuildMavenProject()
    local pom = SearchFileBackwards("pom.xml")
    if pom ~= "" then
        vim.fn.system('mvn -f ' .. pom .. ' compile')
    else
        vim.api.nvim_echo({{ "No pom.xml found.", "WarningMsg" }}, true, {})
    end
end

vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(0, "n", "<F8>", ":lua BuildMavenProject()<CR>", { silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_command('autocmd BufWritePost *.java lua BuildMavenProject()')
```